# using two query in an array with two database connection files

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries and need to display data from both queries. below is what i did with the first query.

```
  <?php
  include 'config/dbconnectorder.php';
  $query="SELECT task_order FROM order";
  $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
  <b><?php echo $row['task_order']; ?></b> 
  <?php } ?>
```

I need to use below query to display the name of the order

```
  include 'config/dbconnectemployee.php';
  $query_emp="SELECT name FROM employee";
  $res_emp=mysqli_query($dbemp, $query_emp);
```

table `order` and `employee`  are from different databases. how can I solve this? Most answers I refer use mysqli_select_db . But i have two different connection for the databases.

Comment: Whats the relation between the two tables? `order` is not a good table name, you will need to encapsulate that in backticks for every use.

Comment: i think this is an http://xyproblem.info/ you're actually looking how to inner join across 2 databases not 2 different queries

Comment: i answered then realised it was a duplicate, removing answer

Comment: How do you match which record from 'employee' to which record from 'order'?

Comment: @BRjava i solved it! already posted answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

here what i did to solve this..

```
<tbody>                              
<?
include 'config/dbconnectorder.php';
$number=1;
$sql_otorder = "SELECT task_order FROM order";  
$res_otorder = mysqli_query($link,$sql_otorder);

while($row_otorder=mysqli_fetch_array($res_otorder)){
?>
<b><?php echo $row['idtask_order']; ?></b>
<b><?php echo $row['task_order']; ?></b> 
<?php } ?>


include 'config/dbconnectemployee.php';
$query_emp="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE fkidorder='".$row["idotorder"]."'";
$res_emp=mysqli_query($dbemp, $query_emp);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res_emp)){
 ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["nama"]; ?></td>      
      </tr>                     
<? }} ?>
</tbody>
```